# Bash, printing of a value

Tags: bash

I have to display the numeric figure below:

```
<td class="sorted"><strong>Impact Factor </strong></td>
<td>162.500</td>
```

I had tried grep, sed, awk but just couldnt make it to work. The numeric figure is in next line, i had tried to use find to locate the top code and storing it as a variable called $temp. Then tried to print the next line, hoping to remove the td quotes after.

Below is my code thanks!

```
temp=$(fgrep '<td class="sorted"><strong>Impact Factor </strong></td>' $i)
impact=$(sed -n '/$temp/ {n;P}' $i)
```

$i has a html page stored.

i can use this portion of the code to pipe the numbers out `| head -n 1 | cut -d'>' -f4- | cut -d'<' -f1` otherwise, but the goal is 162.5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below grep command which uses the PCRE regex.

```
$ grep -Pzo '<td class="sorted"><strong>Impact Factor </strong></td>[^>]*>\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?' file
162.500
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the -A option of grep to get the next line:

```
grep 'sorted' -A1 $i|grep -v sorted|grep td|cut -d">" -f2|cut -d"<" -f1
```

(Note: I've shortened the first grep search string for brevity)